# Can the vspace below a list environment be decoupled from the one above?

Tags: lists, enumerate

Can the vspace below a `list` environment be decoupled from the one above?  Specifically, when I start a theorem with an `enumerate`, I still would like to have `\topsep` placed between the `enumerate` and any text following (within the theorem), but it looks like I have to insert `\vspace{\topsep}` by hand to achieve this.  I wouldn't mind inserting it by hand in my own documents, but I'm in charge of a group of editors, so it would be much better if I could solve the problem in the class file that I provide for them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a precise choice: a list that starts in places such as the beginning of a theorem, that is, when a paragraph has not yet been started and LaTeX is in a “suspended state” because of possible `\label` commands, the `\if@noparlist` conditional is set to true. The definition of `\endtrivlist`, which is responsible for adding the final space, adds `\@topsepadd` vertical space (set equal to `\topsep` plus some adjustments) only if the conditional is false.

Actually, the precise place where the conditional is set to true is after `\item`: theorem environments are a glorified `trivlist` and the theorem statement is processed after an implicit `\item`.

Thus, doing what you ask will have the consequence that an additional space is inserted also after a nested list beginning just after an `\item`.

An idea that comes to mind is issuing `\addvspace\@topsepadd` when `\if@noparlist` is true *and* the list depth is zero at that moment. This would affect also `list` environments starting just after a `flushleft` environment has begun, because, again, `flushleft` is based on `trivlist`. On the other hand, this doesn't seem desirable behavior, so here's the proposed patch:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% Patch a macro in the kernel: use with caution!
\patchcmd{\endtrivlist}
  {\if@noparlist}
  {\if@noparlist\ifnum\@listdepth=\z@\addvspace\@topsepadd\fi}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{A theorem}
\begin{thm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item a
\item b
\end{enumerate}
Some text following.
\end{thm}

\section{A nested enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate}
  \item 1
  \item 2
  \end{enumerate}
\item 3
\end{enumerate}

\section{Enumerate in flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{enumerate}
\item a
\item b
\end{enumerate}
Some text following.
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

### The result with the patch

[image]

### The result without the patch

[image]